# trying to do PHP server validation but error message isnt showing

Tags: php, html, server

Im a beginner with php and Im trying to do server validation on a form. I only have it set up so far so that when the student number is empty an error message is meant to pop up saying Enter Number but this isnt the case. Instead on the page I get a message saying please fill in this feild.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="studentform.php" method="POST">
          <li><label for="student_number">Student Number:</label>
              <input type="text" name="student_number" maxlength=20 required/></li>
              <span class="error">* <?php echo $number_error;?></span>
          <li><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength=20 required/></li>
          <li><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength=20 required/></li>
          <li><label for="address">Address:</label>
            <textarea name="address" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea></li>
          <li><label for="mobile_no">Mobile No:</label>
              <input type="tel" name="mobile_no" placeholder="eg. +353860040400"/></li>
          <li><label for="Date_of_birth">Date-of-birth:</label>
              <input type="date" name="Date_of_birth" required/></li>
          <li><label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
          <li><label for="Major">Major:</label>
              <input type="text" name="Major" required/></li>
          <li><label for="Course">Course:</label>
              <input type="text" name="Course" required/></li>
          <li><label for="Study_Mode">Study Mode:</label>
              <input type="text" name="Study_Mode" required/></li>
          <li><label for="Start_Date">Start Date:</label>
              <input type="date" name="Start_Date" required/></li>
          <li><label for="End_Date">End Date:</label>
              <input type="date" name="End_Date" required/></li>
          <li><button class="submit" type="submit">Register Student</button></li>
      </form>


  </body>


</html>
<?php
$number_error = '';
$number = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  echo "<h3>New Contact Details:</h3>";
  if (empty($_POST["student_number"])) {
    $number_error = "<p> Enter Number</p>";
  } else {
    $number = test_input($_POST["student_number"]);
  }
    echo "<h4>First name:</h4>".$_POST['first_name'];
    echo "<h4>Last name:</h4>".$_POST['last_name'];
    echo "<h4>Address:</h4>".$_POST['address'];
    echo "<h4>Mobile No:</h4>".$_POST['mobile_no'];
    echo "<h4>Date-of-birth:</h4>".$_POST['Date_of_birth'];
    echo "<h4>Gender:</h4>".$_POST['gender'];
    echo "<h4>Major:</h4>".$_POST['Major'];
    echo "<h4>Course:</h4>".$_POST['Course'];
    echo "<h4>Study Mode:</h4>".$_POST['Study_Mode'];
    echo "<h4>Start Date:</h4>".$_POST['Start_Date'];
    echo "<h4>End Date:</h4>".$_POST['End_Date'];


} ?>
```

[Message that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cIHe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have an input with the `required` attribute, so you are using HTML5 validation which specifies whether a form field needs to be filled in before the form can be submitted. And it is firstly checked by the browser, not by your PHP code, and it is called client-side validation. So when you click submit, the request does not reach your code because this error message is shown by the browser.

If you want to disable client side validation for a form in HTML5 add a novalidate attribute to the form element. For example: `<form action="studentform.php" method="POST" novalidate>...</form>`